# Replacing a PDIP-IC with a SOIC-IC

Tags: pcb, soic

On one of my boards we were using integrated circuits with PDIP layout. Some of those ICs died recently, and we wanted to replace the ICs with newer versions. Unfortunately, now we only can buy SOIC packages. Is there a way to mount them on the existing board (with the PDIP-layout) without having to design a new board?

Comment: Typically for things that were in DIP what matters is that you make the electrical connection by some reasonable length, doesn't matter if it's bodge wire.  You can get adapters for some wider DIPs but typically an SOIC won't fit between the rows of a 300 mil one.  Your question lacks details that could let any concerns about signal integrity, etc be addressed.  You might also simply try harder to find the parts in DIP.

Comment: There are SOIC to DIP adapters out there. Search for your specific packages.
If such a specific adapter is not available for your IC, you can design one easily.

Comment: https://www.digikey.com/products/en/connectors-interconnects/sockets-for-ics-transistors-adapters/411?k=soic%20dip%20adapter

Comment: Buy a breakout PCB. SOIC TO DIP.